# Reuse camera calibration parameters?

Tags: calibration, camera-calibration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using a stereo camera set up which I need to recalibrate every time I want to use it. Is there anyway to save the best camera calibraiton parameters I got and just reuse them?

It would probably only work under the assumption that the camera's do not change in orientation with respect to each other, which is fairly trivial to do.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/231569/reuse-camera-calibration-parameters?/) by [Sood](https://answers.ros.org/users/26384/sood/) on ROS Answers with karma: 20 on 2016-04-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-04-10**:
Most of the ROS camera drivers already have functionality for storing the camera calibration on disk or on the camera, and reloading it at startup. Which camera driver are you using?

**Comment by [Sood](https://answers.ros.org/users/26384/sood/) on 2016-04-10**:
The usb_cam driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The next time you calibrate the cameras save the calibration parameters in a .yaml file. Next time you launch the usb_cam node, enter the file path in the camera_info_url parameter. It is easier if you use a launch file so you don't have to remember to do it every time.

---

Originally posted by [Icehawk101](https://answers.ros.org/users/4327/icehawk101/) with karma: 955 on 2016-04-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0